# Instalación PHP en ubuntu 18.04, solo permite PHP7.2

Tags: php7, ubuntu, configuración

Desínstale PHP y sus módulos de un equipo por problemas en la ejecución (previamente tenia PHP 7.2, 7.4 y 8.1, ahora mismo solo puedo instalar PHP7.2

***No encuentra nada en los repositorios para PHP7.4 o PHP8.1***,

He seguido los pasos:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common gnupg2 -y 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update -y
```

y seguidamente:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4 php7.4-fpm php7.4-cli -y
```

Salida:

> Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
> Creando árbol de dependencias
> Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
> Nota, seleccionando «php7.4-cli» para la expresión regular «php7.4»
> Nota, seleccionando «php7.4-json» para la expresión regular «php7.4»
> Nota, seleccionando «php7.4-opcache» para la expresión regular «php7.4»
> Nota, seleccionando «php7.4-common» para la expresión regular «php7.4»
> Nota, seleccionando «libapache2-mod-php7.4» para la expresión regular «php7.4»
> El paquete php7.4-cli no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia
> a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
> encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente

> E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete php7.4-fpm
> E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete usando «*» con «php7.4-fpm»
> E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «php7.4-fpm»
> E: El paquete «php7.4-cli» no tiene un candidato para la instalación

Para PHP 8.1:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.1 php8.1-fpm php8.1-cli -y
```

Salida:

> Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
> Creando árbol de dependencias
> Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
> E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete php8.1
> E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete usando «*» con «php8.1»
> E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «php8.1»
> E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete php8.1-fpm
> E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete usando «*» con «php8.1-fpm»
> E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «php8.1-fpm»
> E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete php8.1-cli
> E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete usando «*» con «php8.1-cli»
> E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «php8.1-cli»

He buscado en los repositorios con:

```
apt-cache search php7
```

Solo aparecen paquetes de *PHP 7.2*

Si busco *php8*, nada.

He buscado en aptitude:

```
aptitude search php7
```

Este encuentra por encima de php7.2, solo `libapache2-mod-php7.4`

> Editado
> *Pueden haberse eliminado otras versiones PHP de los repositorios para Ubuntu Bionic: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic
> En el buscador de paquetes no aparece PHP8, y solo PHP 7.2 de la 7x.*

Comment: En una distribución LTS se prioriza la estabilidad a largo plazo sobre la actualización. Así que no es extraño que no consigas las últimas versiones desde el repositorio oficial. O añades otro repo o compila desde el código fuente.

Comment: @Sal, ¿conoces alguna otra fuete diferente de `ppa:ondrej/php`?
¿O como copiar los paquetes de un equipo en otro?

Comment: No conozco otra fuente, pero [el que mencionas](https://deb.sury.org) lejos de tener malas referencias puede inspirar confianza. Para copiar paquetes considera `apt-clone`.